# Why is the FirebaseAuth.getInstance.uid not the same as the current sender id (returns the receiver) value?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-authentication

[Firebase Realtime DB "Users" Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6tYq.png)
I have a simple chat application with Firebase real time DB. When trying to bind multiple views in the Recycler View, the current sender ID returns the ID of the receiver, so the condition is never accomplished. I tried to check the database and the "Children", but I couldn't reach the solution.

MessageAdapter.kt

```
class MessageAdapter(private var context: Context, messageList: ArrayList<Message>?, senderRoom: String, receiverRoom: String):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder?>() {

    private lateinit var messages: ArrayList<Message>
    private val ITEM_SENT = 1
    private val ITEM_RECEIVED = 2
    private val senderRoom: String
    private val receiverRoom: String

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return if (viewType == ITEM_SENT){
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sent_msg, parent, false)
            SentViewHolder(view)
        } else {
            val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.received_msg, parent, false)
            ReceivedViewHolder(view)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = messages.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //Some Kind of Code
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val newMsg = messages[position]
        return if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid == newMsg.senderId){
            ITEM_SENT
        } else {
            ITEM_RECEIVED
        }
    }

    inner class SentViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding: SentMsgBinding = SentMsgBinding.bind(itemView)
    }

    inner class ReceivedViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        var binding: ReceivedMsgBinding = ReceivedMsgBinding.bind(itemView)
    }
    init {
        if (messageList != null){
            this.messages = messageList
        }
        this.senderRoom = senderRoom
        this.receiverRoom = receiverRoom
    }
}
```

It's clear that getItemViewType() function never returns (ITEM_SENT), because the "newMsg.senderId" returns the receiver id (The first in the screenshot) not the sender(The second in the screenshot image).

So, I try to access the sender id and view the sent message for the sender, but the first condition that returns "ITEM_SENT" didn't accomplished. So, only the receiver can view the sent message!!

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have already said that the problem in the getItemViewType() function, the newMsg.senderId returns another ID (The receiver), so it never equals the sender id from the DB (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid), and only the receiver can watch the sent message.